# Needing to understand why Promise results for inline function not resolving out to intended return result

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am working with learning more about JavaScript promises and ran into an issue when trying to combine some promise logic out of separate functions into a single inline function.  When I pulled it all into a single inline function it is resulting in 'undefined' for the promises return result instead of the intended 'world' value.

[ WORKS as intended, where it resolves out the promise asynchronously, and results in 'world' for the promise response]

```
app.get('/asyncTest', (request, response) => {
    console.log("Request started...");

    var helloResult = hello()
            .then((res)=> {
                console.log('COMPLETED Promise Result (Promise completed): ' + res)
            });

    console.log('Hello Result (immediately after issuing the promise [still in promise object format]): ' + helloResult);

    console.log('Mesage at the end of the request (Should fire before completion of the promise result being fulfilled...');
});


function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}

async function hello() {
    await wait(3000);
    return 'world';
}
```

[NOT WORKING - Results in 'undefined' instead of 'world' for the promise response...]

```
var helloResult = async (r) => { 
                await new Promise(r => {
                    setTimeout(r, 3000);
                    return 'world';
                })
            };

let helloResponse = helloResult().then((res)=> {
    console.log('COMPLETED Promise Result (Promise completed): ' + res)
})
```

[NOT WORKING - Results in 'undefined' instead of 'world' for the promise response...]

```
var helloResult = async () => { 
                await new Promise(r => {
                    setTimeout(r, 3000);
                    return 'world';
                })
                .then((responseData)=> {
                    console.log('COMPLETED Promise Result (Promise completed): ' + responseData)
                })};
```

For some reason the promise in the second 2 attempts to change the code are resulting out in 'undefined' instead of the expected value from the return result of 'world'.

Any advice is appreciate, thank you for your help.

Comment: `async` should be in the `get` callback in the first place (`async (request, response) => {`), if you're planning to hold the promise response value on `helloResult`. Wrapping the inside things in `async` won't do any magic as long as the parent callback is not marked `async`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning from the `Promise` constructor callback in your latter examples. That value is not resolved. You have to call the `resolve` callback in order to pass the value along.

```
await new Promise(r => {
   setTimeout(() => r('world'), 3000);
});
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks @Daniel, I really appreciate it, that is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You have no `return` in `helloResult()` and need to pass argument to `resolve()`

```js
var helloResult = async(r) => {
   return await new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(r, 500, 'world');
  })
};

let helloResponse = helloResult().then((res) => {
  console.log('COMPLETED Promise Result (Promise completed): ' + res)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the confusion.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(1);
  return 2;
}).then(v => console.assert(v===1))
```

In the promise constructor you can return a value but it gets ignored. The value passed down the chain is what is passed to the `resolve` or `reject` functions. So when you do:

```
var helloResult = async (r) => { 
  await new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(r, 3000);
    return 'world';
  })
};
```

It's the same concept. `setTimeout` calls `resolve` (`r`) at the right time but doesn't pass the value ('world') in. In your case you have 2 options that both do the same thing essentially:

```
var helloResult = async (r) => 
  await new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(r, 3000, 'world');
  });

// or 

var helloResult = async (r) =>
  await new Promise(r => {
    setTimeout(()=> r('world'), 3000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

From your second example: `then` is a method on the Promise API so you need to return a promise from `helloResult` for that to have any effect. You're also not resolving that promise once the timeout has completed.

```js
var helloResult = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('world'), 3000);
  });
};

let helloResponse = helloResult().then((res) => {
  console.log('COMPLETED Promise Result (Promise completed): ' + res)
})
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `async/await` you can, but you need to ensure that code containing the `await` sits with a corresponding `async`.

```js
var helloResult = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('world'), 3000);
  });
};

(async () => {
  const response = await helloResult();
  console.log(`COMPLETED Promise Result (Promise completed): ${response}`);
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to fix this by using a `resolve` in your promise, like so:

```
var helloResult = async (r) => { 
                await new Promise(r => {
                    setTimeout(r, 3000);
                    resolve('world');
                })
            };

let helloResponse = helloResult().then((res)=> {
    console.log('COMPLETED Promise Result (Promise completed): ' + res)
})
```

Similarly, this can be done for your second block of code where you have chained a `then` onto the promise.

Comment: No, a promise will wait for all invoked actions to be completed before resolving.

Comment: I don't think thats right. This code doesn't run either